# How To Normalize Feature That Depends Arbitrarily On Date Published

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, normalization

Working on an ML project to predict the number of listens a certain podcast episode of my podcast will get in the first 28 days.

The problem is that when I first started recording the podcast would get 70 listens in the first 28 days while now 2 years later it might get 200 listens just based on the fact that the podcast is more popular now than it was when I first started.

How do you account for this change without the model putting unfair weight on the episodes that are most modern?

For example:

```
Date, Category, Listens, Day Published

Aug 2020, Science, 70, Monday
Aug 2022, Topical, 200, Tuesday
```

I'm worried that the second rows features will be learned to correlate more with higher listens...even though that could just be based on the fact that the podcast as a whole is more popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way is to standardize the value based on a moving average.

For example, calculate the average `avg` number of "listens" in the past 6 months for every podcast, i.e depending on the date of the podcast. Then replace the raw number of listens with the relative rate compared to `avg`, i.e. `rate = (listens - avg) / avg`. Example:

- An old podcast which had 80 listens when the average was 70 is represented as a positive score: {90-70)/70=0.28
- A recent one which has 150 listens when the average is 200 is represented as a negative score: (150-200)/200=-0.25

Of course you can adjust the calculation of the moving average depending on what makes sense for your data. In case the podcasts are not very regular, you could use the last N podcasts instead of the last N months.